# Interpolated strings in F#

Tags: sql, f#, entity-framework-core, formattablestring

I am trying to use the Entity Framework Core interpolated SQL query function in F# which requires a `FormattableString`. However to my surprise it doesn't function as I cannot find a way to convert a regular F# string to that type. I figured just doing what you do in C# would work but it doesn't. Here is the code I currently have:

```
let fromDbUser (u : Entity.User) = 
    {
        name = u.Name
        age = u.Age
        phone = u.Phone
    }

let mname = "Foo" 

let ctx = new Entity.DatabaseContext()
ctx.User.FromSqlInterpolated($"Select * FROM User Where name = {mname};") 
|> Seq.map(fromDbUser)
|> printfn "%A"
```

Running that block of code yields a compile error:

> This token is reserved for future use

I have been trying to google around but I was unable to find any way to get this to work, any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

When this was asked, F# didn't have string interpolation.

Today though, there is an [RFC](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/RFCs/FS-1001-StringInterpolation.md) for it that is merged in [in F# 5.0](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/pull/8907) allowing string interpolation in F#.

---

The error was because the `$` symbol [is reserved](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/84212897422e78a6e628d28d373829130e6e3d62/src/fsharp/lex.fsl#L535) (for 6 years+ as of writing), and will probably be used for string interpolation when it is added.

Answer (score 4):

As Dave pointed out, interpolation isn't implemented yet.
But for methods that absolutely require an `FormattableString` or an `IFormattable`, you can use [FormattableStringFactory.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.formattablestringfactory.create?view=netframework-4.8)

```
let query (sql: FormattableString)  = 
    printfn "%s" (sql.ToString(null, null))

let mname = "Foo"         
let fstr = FormattableStringFactory.Create("Select * FROM User Where name = {0};", mname)

query fstr
```

Answer (score 2):

It's available from F# 5.0.

```ml
> let mname = "Foo" ;;
val mname : string = "Foo"

> let str = $"Select * FROM User Where name = {mname};" ;;
val str : string = "Select * FROM User Where name = Foo;"
```

Check this out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/whats-new/fsharp-50#string-interpolation